# Mongoid::Paranoia delete associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

user.rb model

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paranoia
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy, :autosave => true
end
```

post.rb model

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user
  field :title
end
```

If I run the next command in console:

```
irb(main):020:0> u = User.first
=> #object here
irb(main):021:0> u.delete
=> true
irb(main):022:0> u.posts
=> nil
```

If I try call to **user posts** I can see that all **user posts** has been deleted. I want remove all user posts **only** if user is permanent destroyed from my database with `u.destroy`.

**How can I keep inside of my database all related objects if I delete a object with `Mongoid::Paranoia` `u.delete` for this object can be restore later with `u.restore`**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite the [`remove` method](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/v3.1.2/lib/mongoid/paranoia.rb#L60) in `User` that is provided by `Mongoid::Paranoia` so it omits the `cascade!` call:

```
  def remove(options = {})
    # don't cascade the remove call
    # cascade!
    time = self.deleted_at = Time.now
    paranoid_collection.find(atomic_selector).
      update({ "$set" => { paranoid_field => time }})
    @destroyed = true
    IdentityMap.remove(self)
    Threaded.clear_options!
    true
  end
  alias :delete :remove
```

Now `u.delete` will leave all associated posts intact and `u.delete!` will delete them permanently, too.